# Whether Transactions(Commit, Rollback) will lock any data or table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just want to ask whether using Transactions(Commit, Rollback) will lock any data/table? Please provide me links about this.

Comment: question makes no sense. Depends what you are doing within the transaction...In general, a transaction takes system resources...

Comment: I am inserting a bulk of data from a multi threaded application. I am using transaction to insert data in multiple tables. I just want to ask whether these tables get locked when a transaction started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

It depends on your transaction isolation level for each of the clients. There are several settings, such as `READ COMMITTED`, `READ UNCOMMITTED`, and `REPEATABLE READ`

Comment: Ok, Is this means by default(talking about Read Commited) sql server allows you to insert multiple records concurrently, even if you are using transactions to insert data in multiple tables.

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind, however, that transactions should be closed as soon as possible. It's bad to have a transaction open while waiting for user input, if that's where you're headed.

Comment: These isolation levels only affect the behaviour of reads as their name implies. Doesn't alter `insert` behaviour as this comment trail suggests.

Comment: Right. I may have misread his initial comment. Multiple connections can't insert into the same table concurrently, but they can insert into different tables.